# Photo Upload Validation with React

Tags: reactjs, image, validation, upload, antd

I have this small issue
I am using Ant Design and its components
https://ant.design/components/upload/

I am trying to upload images, and it all works fine, But i need to add a validation to verify if the file is correct. That is if a user renames any other file to a `.jpg` or `.png` extension, i need to validate that and show them an alert.

How can i achieve that, Currently we convert the image in base64 using FileReader

Comment: Did you read the documentation? Check `onChange`, you have the file type there

Comment: also, check `beforeUpload` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function and return something like this.

```
const verifyImage = (img) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.addEventListener('load', event => {
      let picFile = event.target
      let imgNew = new Image()
  imgNew.addEventListener('load', () => {
    resolve(reader.result)
  })
  imgNew.addEventListener('error', () => {
    reject()
  })
  imgNew.src = picFile.result
})
reader.readAsDataURL(img)
  })
}
```

Comment: I used it in `beforeUpload`